# Displaying Data From 4 (Four) Tables in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I just need a simple queries actually,

***Here are my tables:***

> **Information** -> id_info, year, information_name, person_name, country_id, state_id, city_id
>
> **Country** -> id, country_id, country_name
>
> **State** -> id, state_id, country_id, state_name
>
> **City** -> id, city_id, state_id, city_name

I have runs some queries, for example's:

```
                         SELECT * 
                         FROM information, country, state, city 
                         WHERE information.country_id =country.country_id 
                         AND information.state_id = state.state_id
                         AND information.city_id = city.city_id 
                         GROUP BY information.id_info;
```

***My Simple Scripts:***

```
echo '<td>'.$data['country_name'].'</td>

echo '<td>'.$data['state_name'].'</td>

echo '<td>'.$data['city_name'].'</td>

$data-> Is my while script with $query=mysql_query...
```

from the queries above only displaying two (2) data's from my database, but in the database it has five (5) data's.

Then I've trying to delete the Group statement, but the data kept looped and displaying almost 8000 data's, but I only got 5 data on tables.

I've tried everything, left join, right join, inner join....

I need help, I know it's quite simple, but how can I just display all the data normally.

Thanks.

*Here My Full Scripts for displaying the data:*

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Information Name</th>
        <th>Person Name</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Act</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    include('connect.php');

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT *
                  FROM information
                  INNER JOIN country ON information.country_id =country.country_id
                  INNER JOIN state ON information.state_id = state.state_id
                                  INNER JOIN city ON information.city_id = city.city_id
                                  GROUP BY information.country_id, information.state_id, information.city_id") or die(mysql_error());


    if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0){


        echo '<tr><td colspan="6">No data!</td></tr>';

    }else{  


        $no = 1;    
        while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){   

            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$no.'</td>';    
                echo '<td>'.$data['year'].'</td>';  
                echo '<td>'.$data['information_name'].'</td>';  
                echo '<td>'.$data['person_name'].'</td>';   
                echo '<td>'.$data['country_name'].'</td>';  
                echo '<td>'.$data['state_name'].'</td>';    
                echo '<td>'.$data['city_name'].'</td>'; 
                echo '<td><a href="viewinfo.php?id='.$data['id_info'].'">Detail</a> / <a href="edit.php?id='.$data['id_info'].'">Edit</a> / <a href="delete.php?id='.$data['id_info'].'" onclick="return confirm(\'Are You Sure?\')">Delete</a></td>';  
            echo '</tr>';

            $no++;  

        }

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What is your table name ?

Comment: Do you need to use all the fields? Or you need only the country, state and city names?

Comment: @FerrakkemBhuiyan: information, country, state, city

Comment: @Edper: I need all actually, because there are connection's in that queries, as my updated script's above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your GROUP BY and use INNER JOIN :

```
  SELECT *
  FROM information
   INNER JOIN country ON information.country_id =country.country_id
   INNER JOIN state ON information.state_id = state.state_id
   INNER JOIN city ON information.city_id = city.city_id
   GROUP BY information.country_id, information.state_id, information.city_id
```

Comment: Only two data's was displayed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use INNER JOIN assuming that index key is properly used:

```
SELECT country.country_name,
       state.state_name,
       city.city_name
FROM information
INNER JOIN country ON information.country_id = country.country_id
INNER JOIN state ON information.state_id = state.state_id
INNER JOIN city ON information.city_id = city.city_id
```

Comment: Well, it's still the same though, it will displayed 19334 records, but in the database only got five record's. Perhaps I did wrong in my script's, I updated my full scripts above.

Comment: @Kris - show us how you fetch the data. Update your post

Comment: I just did :) updated my full scripts for displaying the data's in a table with edit, delete, and view detail scripts in separated files.

Answer (score 0):

It worked now, *sigh the problem is the table in information, I have to empty the table first.

It quite a lot happened to me, the records was the problem source's, I've been through this a lot. Thank you guys for the help, now it's work perfectly fine.

The two answer above worked perfectly, Thank you.

Comment: Glad that you find the solution Kris. Happy coding and GOD bless.